# Computer only boots after sleep, not shutdown

Tags: windows-10, boot, sleep, shutdown

My PC only boots from sleep, not shutdown. The only way I can boot from shutdown is if I press F11 to open the boot menu and then close the menu without clicking anything but the "x". If I select "sleep" when I turn my computer off, it boots completely fine. I have tried unplugging the computer (not while running) and plugging it back in but that didn't fix the issue.
Specs:

```
 - Windows 10 Build 17134.345 64 bit
 - i7-5820K
 - Gigabyte GTX 960
 - Samsung EVO SSD
 - Crucial MX500
 - MSI X99A SLI plus
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **you have to go to the bios and change the boot order** of your disks, after a start on the 1 samsung disk or crucial a standby makes it go back to the right disk when a reboot apparently makes it change disk and that's why you can only reboot it with the boot option menu.

Comment: Should I have Windows Boot Manager first?

Comment: try crucial and if you're not fine, try windows boot manager you have only two options. And maybe update your bios